# RadiobuttonField Super with Label, Value and Group

Tags: blackberry, radio-button, registration, super

I'm new to Java and Blackberry and i'm stuck with a registration screen, due to the fallowing:

I have a registration screen, where i show 2 radiobuttons, male and female. Only these 'labels' are not for me to write, it's a value and a tag that i request to a webservice.
What i needed was something like:

```
MyRadioButton rb1=(String label, String value, Group rbg);
```

and it's Super(label, value, group); ---this value more of an internal label ID, so to speak, a pk_id.---

so i could, after, retrieve which Rbutton was selected and it's value, so i could send it back when i click the Register Button.

I have an example of how to do it, but not for blackberry:

```
Gender[] gender = WebServCall.GetUserGender();

    if (gender != null && gender.length == 2)
    {

        holder.radiob1.setText(gender[0].genderType);
        holder.radiob1.setTag(gender[0].PK_ID);
        holder.radiob2.setText(gender[1].genderType);
        holder.radiob2.setTag(gender[1].PK_ID);



    }
    else
    {
        //alert
    }
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    RadioButton radiob1;
    RadioButton radiob2;
}
```

(...)

//Get the inserted information, by the user

...
RadioButton register_buffer_Gender1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiob1);
RadioButton register_buffer_Gender2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiob2);

...
boolean check1 = register_buffer_Gender1.isChecked();
boolean check2 = register_buffer_Gender2.isChecked();

....

Could you give and example of how to do this, but for blackberry?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is actually pretty similar in BlackBerry development:

```
//Setting up the buttons
RadioButtonGroup group = new RadioButtonGroup();

RadioButtonField radio1 = new RadioButonField(gender[0].genderType, group);
radio1.setCookie(gender[0].PK_ID);

RadioButtonField radio2 = new RadioButtoNField(gender[1].genderType, group);
radio2.setCookie(gender[1].PK_ID);

add(radio1);
add(radio2);

////////////////////////

//Retrieving info from the buttons
boolean check1 = radio1.isSelected();
boolean check2 = radio2.isSelected();

//or you can use the group
int checkedIndex = group.getSelectedIndex();
```

I would suggest taking a look at the documentation on [RadioButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RadioButtonField.html) and [RadioButtonGroup](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RadioButtonGroup.html), should get you on your way.

Comment: IS  "MyRadioButton Gender1 = rb1;"  THE SAME AS
"RadioButton Gender1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiob1);"  AND HOW DO I DO THIS "
  if (check1)
   Gender= Gender1.getTag().toString();        else
 Gender = Gender2.getTag().toString();"? THIS IS FOR GETTING THE GENDER VALUE SO I CAN SEND IT BACK TO THE WEBSERVICDE, WHEN REGISTERING. ALL CONSIDERING MY FIRST POST.

Comment: Is MyRadioButton what you're using in BB? If so then yeah, but you can just use rb1 without needing to assign another variable to it. With regard to the second part, you can use rb1 (or Gender1 if you're reassigning) and call rb1.getLabel() to get the text of the RadioButton, or if you're trying to get the PK_ID out of it you can call rb1.getCookie().toString() assuming PK_ID is a String.